# Will my domain automatically renew?

Tags: domain-registration

I received this email from enom.

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------- From: eNom Support  Date: Tue, May 5, 2015 at 2:09 PM Subject:
>   XXXXXX.com will expire on May 15, 2015 To: niklasXXXXXXX@gmail.com
>
> Dear Niklas XXXXXX:
>
> We just wanted to let you know that XXXXXXXX.com will expire on
>   May 15, 2015. To renew this domain, please visit
>   https://support.google.com/a/answer/4377734 today.
>
> If you do not renew your domain by May 15, 2015 you will no longer own
>   the domain, and it will be available for registration by other
>   parties.
>
> Sincerely, eNom Support

If I login to google.com/a and look at billing in the admin console, it says that my domain will renew the 15th. But how can I make sure that this is so?

### Update

It seems google has answered my question by emailing to my other address that my domain will renew automagically:

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------- From: The Google Apps Team  Date: Fri, May 1, 2015 at 4:53 PM Subject:
>   Registration of XXXXXX.com will renew automatically in 7 days To:
>   admin@XXXXXX.com, niklasXXXXXX@gmail.com
>
> ```
>       Billing
> ```
>
> Hello,
>
> Your domain name, XXXXXX.com, is configured for automatic renewal with
>   registrar enom on May 8, 2015. Each registration renewal is valid for
>   one year.
>
> Google will charge your account after the renewal is complete. To
>   ensure uninterrupted service, please follow these directions to update
>   your payment method if needed.
>
> If you don’t want to renew your domain name or continue using Google
>   Apps, see Domain Registration Renewals to turn off automatic renewals.
>
> ```
> Sincerely, The Google Apps Team
> ```
>
> © 2014 Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043
>   You have received this mandatory email service announcement to update
>   you about important changes to your Google Apps product or account.

Comment: Most allow for manual renewal along with the auto notification, it's not a bad idea to go ahead and do that so you don't have the auto-renewal die from something careless like a card expiration date, you know ahead of time when you get the reject as opposed to afterwards and praying the "Grace Period" isn't graceless and fumbling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eNom is a registrar, but this mail is making it sound like Google is the registrar. Make sure you are logging into the correct registrar console. This is where your domain "rental" is managed/updated/transferred. It would be the same place where you got the domain from and set initial nameservers...the place you pay yearly for the domain. Then attempt to renew it yourself to be assured that all is good. No sense waiting 9 more days unless you are short on cash or something. If you are even 10 seconds late, or worst case the registrar software/site/server ironically fails, a next in line domain-shark could sniper it from you.

**As a note,** some registrars spam when it comes near to your renew date and make it sound like you manage the domain through them. Make sure eNom isn't trying to phish you into renewing through them instead of where it was initially registered at.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Now I also received an email directly from google, from which the domain was bought initially, saying that my domain indeed will renew automagically soon. So your answer is correct that it matters where the domain initially was purchased.

Comment: "If you are even 10 seconds late, ... a next in line domain-shark could sniper it from you." - You should at least have a couple of weeks during which time you should be able to renew without penalty. (Although the site might appear down very soon after expiry.)